# ROS on 32bit system

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Is it possible to install ROS on a 32 bit system? For the OS i will use tinkerOS v2.0.1. I was thinking about buying the asus tinker board because it is more powerfull than the PI 3, but it has a 32 bit CPU, so I'm not sure it will work.

Sorry if it's a stuppid question.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272075/ros-on-32bit-system/) by [MaximeRector](https://answers.ros.org/users/29590/maximerector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2017-10-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tjadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/31352/tjadhav/) on 2017-10-02**:
I'm using Nvidia TK1 which is a 32-bit cpu with Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit. Seems to be working ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a long time i386 was the most common platform since it was the default install for Ubuntu.

Almost all ROS packages work find on both I386 and arm32(armhf) packages. We have only recently turned off i386 builds for the latest ROS distro due to lack of use: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#lunar-loggerhead-may-2017-may-2019 But as it says packages are still expected to build on i386.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MaximeRector](https://answers.ros.org/users/29590/maximerector/) on 2017-10-03**:
Thank you for your answer! But where can I find the installation guide for an arm32 running tinkerOS (Debian 9)? I couldn't find it on the Lunar installation page http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Debian, only for amd64/arm64.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-10-03**:
Yes, as I mentioned we no longer build binaries for i386 as of lunar. If you want to use Lunar on i386 you'll need to build from source: http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Source

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-03**:
@tfoote: the Asus Tinker Board runs on a [RK3288](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockchip_RK3288) - that is a Rockchip ARMv7-A derivative. No x86 there :).

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-10-03**:
Ahh, sorry I'm not familiar with the board. But the same goes for armhf  (v7) you'll need to compile from source.